# Ways to replace the phrase "after all?"

Tags: creative-writing

I recently noticed I use "after all" very often. But unlike other phrases, I never seem to find a way to replace it. Some examples:

> Like the books, they hadn't moved a single inch. Erin found this
>   strange. Even the tiniest shaking would have been enough shift their
>   position. Aluminum was as light as feather **after all.**
>
> ---
>
> Eri knew clearly what it was. But she couldn't make herself bring up
>   the topic. To her, it was like a shapeless creature moving in the
>   dark. An adversary she wanted to avoid at all cost. Because, **after
>   all**, how could you fight something that didn't have a definite form?
>
> ---
>
> “Now I finally see that God didn't approve our marriage. You're a
>   Buddhist **after all**, and He clearly didn't want us to be together.
>   Somehow I knew it all along. Yet I still decided to go against Him.
>
> ---
>
> "I know you're worried about your mother. **After all**, this is the first
>   time you're dealing with something like this.

How could the passages above be rewritten in order to avoid **"after all"**?

(By the way, this is 9000 word short story. And "after all" is used four times. Maybe that isn't so bad?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the phrase.

You might retain it for one character, to give a little POV quirk. Otherwise, none of the sentences need it.

Comment: Absolutely right. It's a useless phrase.